# Viewing Ipython Notebooks' line based diff in VS Code while using the Python extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I wonder how others use the diff view for notebooks in VS Code. With the recent updates the diff view change when I use the [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) (which includes the [Jupyter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter)).

So before I used to see the line base text diffs, which I still see if I turn off the Python extension:

[image: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter]

When I turn the Python extension on, I see a one-to-one comparison where I do not see much if the notebooks are a bit more complicated (changing some details in a Markdown-Cell):
[image]

**Questions**

- Is there a way to get to the line-based first diff view using some command(s) other than turning the extension off?

I am on Windows and I tried to turn off several settings in the extension(s), without seeing any difference:
[image]

I also remember there being a "do not show automatically in notebook editor" setting, but I cannot see it right now! I have to manuelly start the notebook viewer in the File-Tab (first) as I want though, so it is "off".

Any ideas what I am missing or do you think this is a bug?

Comment: an older issue regarding the Python extension on [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88685)

Comment: -You could try the method in this link to test this process in "[Visual Studio Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)": [Git diff for ipynb files is being replaced by the notebook editor](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/633#issuecomment-817354116)

Comment: Thanks a lot @JillCheng. In [Visual Studio Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) the richer diff (using nbdime ?) is working! And the setting referenced activates the line based diff view!

Comment: Do you know by chance if commits of single cells is a planned future feature?

Comment: -You could follow the Github link in my comments or you could create a new GitHub submission.

Comment: If my answer solves the problem, please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as an answer to help others find this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the method in this link to test this process in "[Visual Studio Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)": [Git diff for ipynb files is being replaced by the notebook editor](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/633#issuecomment-817354116)

Answer (score 0):

Following Jill Cheng's comment, I know see the "rich" diff on default (and can turn it off using the settings snippet referenced:

[image]

Uncommenting these settings will give me the line-based diff, if I need to stage only parts of the notebook.

[image]